# Calling a C# web service from another C# web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am working on a project where I have a a program or web page which calls a C# Soap Web Service. I need this web service to then call another Web Service. However, I have a problem that when the second soap web service is added to the first web service I get an error 500 page appear saying none of the supported bindings were found.

The second WebService is called Web Reference and I am calling it by using WebReference.BasicHttpBinding_ServiceName.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Without seeing some sample code, it's hard to tell what the problem could be.

Comment: without more information, we won't be help to help you

Answer (score 3):

-> Please Ensure correct binding is used.

-> Add service reference of first service in second service.

-> Ensure the services are up and running.

It should work fine.

Comment: Yes, and note you should be using "Add Service Reference", not "Add Web Reference".